# If Condition to check the length of string in XSLT and Mapping

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a requirement in which I have to check the length of string of field REF. If it is less than 6, then we need to append 0 in prefix else print the value.

We are mapping XB value to REF by providing XPath. I am beginner in this and tried a couple of statements but it didn't work for me.

Input:

```
<Group xmlns="">
  <ITM xmlns="">
     <>
     <>   
    <REF>123</REF>
     <>
     <>
  </ITM>
</Group>
```

Output:

```
<FID>
  <ID>
    <ED>
       Hard coded values
     </ED>
      <E1>
        <XB>000123</XB>
       </E1>

  </ID>
</FID>
```

XSLT:

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
         <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
          xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result- 
             prefixes="#all" >

          <xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" 
                />
             <xsl:template match="/">

                 <FID>
                         <ID>
                                  <ED>
                                  <xsl:element name="TA">
                    <xsl:text>ED1</xsl:text>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="MA">
                    <xsl:text>123</xsl:text>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="DOC">
                    <xsl:text>0000</xsl:text>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="DOCL">
                    <xsl:text>731</xsl:text>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="STA">
                    <xsl:text>53</xsl:text>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="DIR">
                    <xsl:text>2</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:element>
        </ED>
  <E1> 
  <xsl:element name="BU">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Mapping by giving XPATH"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="BL">
                    <xsl:value-of select=""/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="BL">
                    <xsl:value-of select=""/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="BU">
                    <xsl:value-of select=""/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="WW">
                    <xsl:value-of select=""/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="TC">
                    <xsl:text>FB01</xsl:text>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="XB">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Need to Map REF value here with 
                 condition"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="WA">
                    <xsl:value-of select=""/>
                </xsl:element>
        </E1>
      </ID>
     </FID>
```

Now for XB I have to implement the condition if it is less than 6, then we need to append 0 in prefix else print the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your element names are static, it is easier (less typing, and easier to read) to use element literals. Rather than the `xsl:element name="XB">` constructor, just use `<XB>`. Generally, the only time that you need to use `xsl:element` is when the element name is dynamically constructed.

From your example XML, I'm assuming that the XPath pointing to your `REF` element was `/Group/ITM/REF`.

If the REF value is always a number, then [`format-number()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-format-number) would be the easiest:

```
<XB>
  <xsl:value-of select="format-number(/Group/ITM/REF, '000000')"/>
</XB>
```

If the REF value is a string, then you could `concat()` use `substring()`

```
<XB>
  <xsl:variable name="$ref" select="/Group/ITM/REF"/>
  <xsl:variable name="pad" select="'000000'"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring(
                          concat($pad, $ref), 
                          string-length($ref) + 1, 
                          string-length($pad)
                        )"/>
</XB>
```

Applying to your XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="#all" >

    <xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <FID>
            <ID>
                <ED>
                   <TA>ED1</TA>
                   <MA>123</MA>
                   <DOC>0000</DOC>
                   <DOCL>731</DOCL>
                   <STA>53</STA>
                   <DIR>2</DIR>
                </ED>
                <E1> 
                    <BU>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Mapping by giving XPATH"/>
                    </BU>
                    <BL><xsl:value-of select=""/></BL>
                    <BL><xsl:value-of select=""/></BL>
                    <BU><xsl:value-of select=""/></BU>
                    <WW><xsl:value-of select=""/></WW>
                    <TC><xsl:text>FB01</xsl:text></TC>
                    <XB>
                        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(/Group/ITM/REF, '000000')"/>
                    </XB>
                    <WA><xsl:value-of select=""/></WA>
                </E1>
            </ID>
        </FID>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Actually, I have XML tags and inside that if I am using then I am getting below error:ment xsl:template must always be a child of xsl:stylesheet or xsl:transform.It is like <E1></E1>, has so many filed and one of the field is REF..How should I use template then ..Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can’t put an XSLT template inside of a template. Update your question with your XSLT, or at least with the template that is converting the REF.

Comment: I have updated the input, mentioned some points and updated XLST...Now could you please have a look..Thank you